# Is there a better way to get this element/node with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I think the best way to explain this is via some code. Basically the only way to identify the TR I need inside the table (i've already reached the table itself and named it annual_income_statement) is by the text of the first TD in the TR, like this:

this may be helpful to know, too:

*actual* html:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&fstype=iii'))
```

html snippet:

```
<div id="incannualdiv">
  <table id="fs-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>..</tr>
      ...
      <tr>
        <td>Net Income</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

original xpath

```
irb(main):161:0> annual_income_statement = doc.xpath("//div[@id='incannualdiv']/table[@id='fs-table']/tbody")
```

```
irb(main):121:0> a = nil
=> nil
irb(main):122:0> annual_income_statement.children.each { |e| if e.text.include? "Net Income" and e.text.exclude? "Ex"
irb(main):123:2>   a = e.text
irb(main):124:2> end }
=> 0
irb(main):125:0> a
=> "Net Income\n\n191.00\n611.00\n254.00\n-1,151.00\n"
irb(main):127:0> a.split "\n"
=> ["Net Income", "", "191.00", "611.00", "254.00", "-1,151.00"]
```

but is there a better way?

more details:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&fstype=iii'))
div = doc.at "div[@id='incannualdiv']" #div containing the table i want
table = div.at 'table' #table containing tbody i want
tbody = table.at 'tbody' #tbody containing tr's I want
trs = tbody.at 'tr' #SHOULD be all tr's of that table/tbody - but it's only the first TR?
```

I expect that last bit to give me ALL the TR's (which would include the TD i'm looking for)
but in fact it *only gives me the first TR*

Comment: The question asks how to identify that tr, so that's what I showed you how to do.

Comment: I already answered this question. Ask another one and I'll answer that too, but don't do it here.

Comment: haha, ok, fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is probably:

```
table.at 'tr:has(td[1][text()="Net Income"])'
```

**Edit**

More info:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<EOF
<div id="incannualdiv">
  <table id="fs-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>..</tr>
      ...
      <tr>
        <td>Net Income</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>..</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
EOF
table = doc.at 'table'
table.at('tr:has(td[1][text()="Net Income"])').to_s
#=> "<tr>\n<td>Net Income</td>\n        <td>100</td>\n      </tr>\n"
```

Comment: hmm..that didn't work for some reason. i've added the original xpath in my post.

Comment: Showing the html would be better. Maybe change `=` to `*=` if there's surrounding whitespace.

Comment: the original html is complicated. it's located here https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AAA&fstype=iii

Comment: maybe i'm just doing it wrong: `irb(main):166:0> annual_income_statement.at 'tr:has(td[1][text()="Net Income"])'
=> nil`

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, see my edit to see that it works.

Comment: can you point me to the documentation for the ":has" syntax you're using? when i use what you used in your edit against the actual html, I get an empty string.

Comment: Check that you're not using an old version of nokogiri. Here are the css specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Comment: I think I see what's happening, the .at call is only giving me the first TR - i'll explain in my post.